# Como gravar várias informações em varias classes usando apenas uma classe que grava?

Tags: java, swing

O meu problema é o seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um programa que tem vários botões que correspondem a certos alunos, dentro de cada aluno eu tenho informação pessoal sobre e somente esse Aluno, tenho uma classe que grava tudo da mesma forma só que eu queria em vez de eu estar a fazer cada classe gravadora para cada aluno queria que em cada aluno ele fosse buscar essa classe e se tivesse vindo do aluno X ele gravava no alunoX.txt se fosse do aluno Y gravava no alunoY.txt

```java
public class Gravação_Dados extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextPane textArea;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Gravação_Dados frame = new Gravação_Dados();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Gravação_Dados() {
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Jo\u00E3o Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\Science-Classroom-icon.png"));
        setTitle("Grava\u00E7\u00E3o Notas");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Detalhes/Notas");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 59, 89, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(100, 59, 317, 123);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        textArea = new  JTextPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Gravar");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try
                {
                    FileWriter writer= new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt");
                    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter (writer);

                    textArea.write(bw);
                    bw.close();
                    textArea.setText("");
                    textArea.requestFocus();
                    dispose();
                }
                catch(Exception e1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
                }
            }

        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(293, 205, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        final JButton Abrir = new JButton("Abrir");
        Abrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Abrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        try
                        {
                            FileReader reader=new FileReader("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt");
                            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader (reader);
                            textArea.read(br, null);
                            br.close();
                            textArea.requestFocus();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e1){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,  e1);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        Abrir.setBounds(168, 205, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(Abrir);

        JButton Preciso_de_ajuda = new JButton("Preciso de Ajuda");
        Preciso_de_ajuda.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Ajuda().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        Preciso_de_ajuda.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jo\u00E3o Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\dica.png"));
        Preciso_de_ajuda.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
        Preciso_de_ajuda.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        Preciso_de_ajuda.setBounds(0, 0, 444, 23);
        contentPane.add(Preciso_de_ajuda);
    }
}
```

Basicamente eu queria que quando o utilizador carregasse no botão do aluno1 por exemplo o programa soubesse que eu queria gravar esta informação no file.txt correspondente .
Aqui esta a edição este é o menu principal:

```java
public class PARTE2 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PARTE2 frame = new PARTE2();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public PARTE2() {
        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Jo\u00E3o Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\icons\\Science-Classroom-icon.png"));
        setTitle("Planta da Sala de Aula");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


        JButton PC_1 = new JButton("PC 1");
        PC_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno1_Magda().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_1.setBounds(10, 586, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_1);

        JButton PC_2 = new JButton("PC 2");
        PC_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno2_Carolina().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_2.setBounds(10, 496, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_2);

        JButton PC_3 = new JButton("PC 3");
        PC_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new Aluno3_Pedro().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_3.setBounds(10, 406, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_3);

        JButton PC_4 = new JButton("PC 4");
        PC_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno4_Alexandre ().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_4.setBounds(10, 316, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_4);

        JButton PC_5 = new JButton("PC 5");
        PC_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno5_Tomas ().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        PC_5.setBounds(10, 226, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_5);

        JButton PC_6 = new JButton("PC 6");
        PC_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno6_Raul().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_6.setBounds(10, 136, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_6);

        JButton PC_8 = new JButton("PC 8");
        PC_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno8_Jorge().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        JButton PC_7 = new JButton("PC 7");
        PC_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno7_Ruben().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_7.setBounds(10, 46, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_7);
        PC_8.setBounds(269, 46, 200, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_8);

        JButton PC_9 = new JButton("PC 9");
        PC_9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno9_Joao().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_9.setBounds(469, 46, 200, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_9);

        JButton PC_10 = new JButton("PC 10");
        PC_10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno10_Miguel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_10.setBounds(669, 46, 200, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_10);

        JButton PC_11 = new JButton("PC 11");
        PC_11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno11_Diogo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_11.setBounds(869, 46, 200, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_11);

        JButton PC_12 = new JButton("PC 12");
        PC_12.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno12_Miguel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_12.setBounds(1214, 46, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_12);

        JButton PC_13 = new JButton("PC 13");
        PC_13.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno13_Francisco().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_13.setBounds(1214, 136, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_13);

        JButton PC_14 = new JButton("PC 14");
        PC_14.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno14_Ze().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_14.setBounds(1214, 226, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_14);

        JButton PC_15 = new JButton("PC 15");
        PC_15.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno15_Floriano().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_15.setBounds(1214, 316, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_15);

        JButton PC_16 = new JButton("PC 16");
        PC_16.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno16_Ruben().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_16.setBounds(1214, 406, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_16);

        JButton PC_17 = new JButton("PC 17");
        PC_17.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno17_Edmara().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        PC_17.setBounds(1214, 497, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(PC_17);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1362, 21);
        contentPane.add(menuBar);

        JMenu ficheiro = new JMenu("Ficheiro ");
        menuBar.add(ficheiro);

        JMenuItem sair = new JMenuItem("Sair");
        sair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object[] options = { "Sim", "Não" };
                int selectedOption=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "   Deseja realmente sair do programa?", "Planta Sala-Sair",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                null, options, options[0]);

                 if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                     dispose();
                 }
            }
        });
        sair.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        sair.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        ficheiro.add(sair);

        JMenu mnAjuda = new JMenu("Ajuda");
        menuBar.add(mnAjuda);

        JMenuItem precisoajuda = new JMenuItem("Preciso de Ajuda");
        mnAjuda.add(precisoajuda);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_1 = new JMenuItem("Sobre");
        mntmNewMenuItem_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Menu_Sobre().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        mnAjuda.add(mntmNewMenuItem_1);

        JButton Secretaria = new JButton("Secret\u00E1ria");
        Secretaria.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        Secretaria.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Relatorio_().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        Secretaria.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        Secretaria.setBounds(404, 529, 554, 141);
        contentPane.add(Secretaria);
    }
}
```

Que vai dar a janela do respetivo aluno:

```java
public class Aluno7_Ruben extends JFrame {

    protected static final File texto1 = null;
    private JPanel contentPane;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Aluno7_Ruben frame = new Aluno7_Ruben();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Aluno7_Ruben() {
        setResizable(false);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Jo\u00E3o Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\icon\\Science-Classroom-icon.png"));


        setTitle("PC7-Ruben Gato");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Detalhes/Notas:");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 106, 194, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Localiza\u00E7\u00E3o da avaria:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 11, 169, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        String texto = "";

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                texto += (char) content;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 128, 414, 85);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        final JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(texto);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea1);

        textArea1.setEditable(false);
        textArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);



        final JCheckBox Teclado = new JCheckBox ("Teclado");
        Teclado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (Teclado.isSelected()){
                    try {
                        String texto_teclado = "O Teclado está danificado";
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt", true));
                        writer.write(texto_teclado);
                        writer.newLine();
                        textArea1.append(texto_teclado+"\n");
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Teclado.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
        Teclado.setBounds(6, 54, 94, 23);
        contentPane.add(Teclado);

        final JCheckBox  Rato = new JCheckBox ("Rato");
        Rato.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (Rato.isSelected()){
                    try {
                        String texto_rato = "O Rato está danificado";
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt", true));
                        writer.write(texto_rato);
                        textArea1.append(texto_rato+"\n");
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    }
                }
                else{
                }
            }
        });
        Rato.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
        Rato.setBounds(98, 54, 81, 23);
        contentPane.add(Rato);

        final JCheckBox  Monitor = new JCheckBox ("Monitor");
        Monitor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (Monitor.isSelected()){
                    try {
                        String texto_monitor = "O Monitor está danificado";
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt", true));
                        writer.write(texto_monitor);
                        textArea1.append(texto_monitor+"\n");
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    }
                }
                else{
                }       
            }
        });
        Monitor.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
        Monitor.setBounds(181, 54, 96, 23);
        contentPane.add(Monitor);

        final JCheckBox Torre = new JCheckBox ("Torre");
        Torre.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (Torre.isSelected()){
                    try {
                        String texto_torre = "A Torre está danificada";
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt", true));
                        writer.write(texto_torre );
                        textArea1.append(texto_torre +"\n");
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    }
                }
                else{
                }   
            }       
        });
        Torre.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
        Torre.setBounds(288, 54, 109, 23);
        contentPane.add(Torre);

        JButton Adicionar_notas = new JButton("Escrever novas notas");
        Adicionar_notas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                FAZJA(evt);
            }
        });

        Adicionar_notas.setBounds(137, 224, 159, 23);
        contentPane.add(Adicionar_notas);
    }

    protected void FAZJA(ActionEvent evt) {
        this.dispose();
        new Gravação_Dados().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MeuChapeu não percebo porque editou a minha pergunta eu sou português e não brasileiro portanto não tem o direito de corrigir coisas que estão bem, para a próxima tente ajudar as pessoas em vez de fazer correções por tudo e por nada

Comment: se percebi direito o teu problema está no `write` e no `reader` que querias que fosse dinâmico? isto é que fosse criado esse caminho automaticamente?

Comment: @JoaoGil Lamento que a edição tenha lhe desagradado, sinta-se livre para [revertê-la](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/41913/revisions) se achar apropriado. De minha parte, entretanto, creio que ela aprimorou sim a pergunta (por formatar corretamente o código) e, embora eu não seja versado em pt_PT, vejo que um dos revisores que [aprovaram essa edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21695) é, e se ele não encontrou problemas nessa edição eu confio no seu julgamento (fique à vontade para discordar entretanto).

Comment: @mgibsonbr só para completar o teu comentário, uma vez que isso aconteceu comigo, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1700/editar-alterar-conte%C3%BAdo-da-resposta tem aqui um problema igual que levei ao meta, assim dá para ficar mais esclarecido...

Comment: A implementação precisa necessariamente ser dessa forma, criando um arquivo `.txt` por aluno? Seria melhor utilizar um `SGBD` para persistência das informações, ou então um arquivo `XML`.

Comment: pois eu desde o inicio que tento gravar em documentos txt pois não sei usar SGBD nem arquivos XML, mas mesmo assim tenho ideia que isto seria por exemplo uma variável chamada numero por exemplo e eu iniciava e declarava essa variavel na classe de cada aluno quando usasse a classe gravadora tinha um switch case,  case numero=1 grava no aluno1.txt case numero=2 grava no aluno2.txt é possivel de alguma maneira fazer isso? @mxn

Comment: @jsantos1991 sim eu queria que o programa soubesse donde é que tinha vindo os dados para depois grava-los nos ficheiros certos

Comment: @JoaoGil eu já percebi o que tu queres fazer(penso eu), mas não sei como te explicar, isto porque não sei quem é que chama essa classe `gravar_dados`, contudo vou elaborar uma resposta a ver se te ajuda...

Comment: `new Aluno9_Joao().setVisible(true);`, `new Aluno8_Jorge().setVisible(true);`, `new Aluno5_Tomas ().setVisible(true);`. Por favor, melhore a orientação a objetos deste negócio rápido. Isso está horrível. Não copie e cole código! Deste jeito, você está criando um monstro e daqui a pouco ele vai te devorar!

Answer (score 3):

O seu código tem uma longa série de problemas. Vamos tentar arrumar tudo.

### Primeiro passo:

Temos que evitar este código copiado e colado em tudo que é lugar:

```java
        final JCheckBox Teclado = new JCheckBox ("Teclado");
        Teclado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (Teclado.isSelected()){
                    try {
                        String texto_teclado = "O Teclado está danificado";
                        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter(NOTAS, true));
                        writer.write(texto_teclado);
                        writer.newLine();
                        textArea1.append(texto_teclado+"\n");
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Teclado.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
        Teclado.setBounds(6, 54, 94, 23);
        contentPane.add(Teclado);
```

A solução para isso é encapsular a criação desta `JCheckBox` em alguns métodos. Vou colocar um método para salvar no arquivo e outro para criar a checkbox:

```java
    private static final String NOTAS = "C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt";

    private void salvar(String texto) {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NOTAS, true))) {
            writer.write(texto);
            writer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Um erro inesperado ocorreu:\n" + e1.toString());
        }
    }

    private JCheckBox criarCheckDanificado(String nome, boolean masculino, final JTextArea area, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        final JCheckBox equipamento = new JCheckBox(nome);
        equipamento.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (equipamento.isSelected()) {
                    String texto;
                    if (masculino) {
                        texto = "O " + nome + " está danificado";
                    } else {
                        texto = "A " + nome + " está danificada";
                    }
                    salvar(texto);
                    area.append(texto + "\n");
                }
            }
        });
        equipamento.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
        equipamento.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
        contentPane.add(equipamento);
        return equipamento;
    }
```

### Segundo passo:

Ter várias telas de alunos, uma para cada aluno é péssimo, pois isso significa um monte de duplicação de código. A única coisa que há de diferente entre essas telas é o número do PC e o nome do aluno, então podemos parametrizar isso para criar uma classe `Aluno` única. A parametrização é feita ao definir o nome e o número do aluno no construtor.

Já vou aproveitar e colocar os caminhos de arquivos em constantes e também colocar o `setVisible(true);` dentro do construtor, uma vez que sempre que este é chamado, queremos que a tela já fique visível.

```java
public class Aluno extends JFrame {

    private static final String ICON = "C:\\Users\\Jo\u00E3o Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\icon\\Science-Classroom-icon.png";
    private static final String NOTAS = "C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt";

    protected static final File texto1 = null;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private int numero;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome do aluno.");
                    String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o nome do aluno.");
                    Aluno frame = new Aluno(numero, nome);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void salvar(String texto) {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NOTAS, true))) {
            writer.write(texto);
            writer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Um erro inesperado ocorreu:\n" + e1.toString());
        }
    }

    private JCheckBox criarCheckDanificado(String nome, boolean masculino, final JTextArea area, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        final JCheckBox equipamento = new JCheckBox(nome);
        equipamento.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (equipamento.isSelected()) {
                    String texto;
                    if (masculino) {
                        texto = "O " + nome + " está danificado";
                    } else {
                        texto = "A " + nome + " está danificada";
                    }
                    salvar(texto);
                    area.append(texto + "\n");
                }
            }
        });
        equipamento.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
        equipamento.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
        contentPane.add(equipamento);
        return equipamento;
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Aluno(int numero, String nome) {
        this.numero = numero;
        setResizable(false);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ICON));
        setTitle("PC" + numero + "-" + nome);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Detalhes/Notas:");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 106, 194, 23);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Localiza\u00E7\u00E3o da avaria:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 11, 169, 20);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
        File file = new File(NOTAS);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        String texto = "";

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                texto += (char) content;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 128, 414, 85);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(texto);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea1);
        textArea1.setEditable(false);
        textArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JCheckBox teclado = criarCheckDanificado("Teclado", true, textArea1, 6, 54, 94, 23);
        JCheckBox rato = criarCheckDanificado("Rato", true, textArea1, 98, 54, 81, 23);
        JCheckBox monitor = criarCheckDanificado("Monitor", true, textArea1, 181, 54, 96, 23);
        JCheckBox torre = criarCheckDanificado("Torre", false, textArea1, 288, 54, 109, 23);

        JButton adicionarNotas = new JButton("Escrever novas notas");
        adicionarNotas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                fazJa(evt);
            }
        });

        adicionarNotas.setBounds(137, 224, 159, 23);
        contentPane.add(adicionarNotas);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void fazJa(ActionEvent evt) {
        this.dispose();
        new Gravação_Dados().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Observe que agora temos uma só classe `Aluno` e uma vez que encapsulamos a lógica da criação das checkboxes, ela ficou bem mais limpa que a(s) original(is).

### Terceiro passo:

Na sua classe `PARTE2`, a lógica da criação dos botões é bastante repetitiva. Vou extraí-la também em uma função separada para simplificar:

```java
    private JButton criarBotao(int numero, String nome, int x, int y) {
        JButton pc = new JButton("PC " + numero);
        pc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno(numero, nome);
            }
        });
        pc.setBounds(x, y, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(pc);
        return pc;
    }
```

E então é assim que a sua classe fica:

```java
public class PARTE2 extends JFrame {

    private static final String PLANTA = "C:\\Users\\Jo\u00E3o Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\icons\\Science-Classroom-icon.png";
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PARTE2 frame = new PARTE2();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private JButton criarBotao(int numero, String nome, int x, int y) {
        JButton pc = new JButton("PC " + numero);
        pc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Aluno(numero, nome);
            }
        });
        pc.setBounds(x, y, 138, 84);
        contentPane.add(pc);
        return pc;
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public PARTE2() {
        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(PLANTA));
        setTitle("Planta da Sala de Aula");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton PC_1 = criarBotao(1, "Magda", 10, 586);
        JButton PC_2 = criarBotao(2, "Carolina", 10, 496);
        JButton PC_3 = criarBotao(3, "Pedro", 10, 406);
        JButton PC_4 = criarBotao(4, "Alexandre", 10, 3164);
        JButton PC_5 = criarBotao(5, "Tomas", 10, 226);
        JButton PC_6 = criarBotao(6, "Raul", 10, 136);
        JButton PC_7 = criarBotao(7, "Ruben Gato", 10, 436);
        JButton PC_8 = criarBotao(8, "Jorge", 269, 46);
        JButton PC_9 = criarBotao(9, "Joao", 469, 46);
        JButton PC_10 = criarBotao(10, "Miguel", 669, 46);
        JButton PC_11 = criarBotao(11, "Diogo", 869, 46);
        JButton PC_12 = criarBotao(12, "Miguel", 1214, 46);
        JButton PC_13 = criarBotao(13, "Francisco", 1214, 136);
        JButton PC_14 = criarBotao(14, "Ze", 1214, 226);
        JButton PC_15 = criarBotao(15, "Floriano", 1214, 316);
        JButton PC_16 = criarBotao(16, "Ruben", 1214, 406);
        JButton PC_17 = criarBotao(17, "Edmara", 1214, 497);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 1362, 21);
        contentPane.add(menuBar);

        JMenu ficheiro = new JMenu("Ficheiro");
        menuBar.add(ficheiro);

        JMenuItem sair = new JMenuItem("Sair");
        sair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object[] options = { "Sim", "Não" };
                int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Deseja realmente sair do programa?", "Planta Sala-Sair",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

                if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    dispose();
                }
            }
        });
        sair.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        sair.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
        ficheiro.add(sair);

        JMenu mnAjuda = new JMenu("Ajuda");
        menuBar.add(mnAjuda);

        JMenuItem precisoajuda = new JMenuItem("Preciso de Ajuda");
        mnAjuda.add(precisoajuda);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_1 = new JMenuItem("Sobre");
        mntmNewMenuItem_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Menu_Sobre().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        mnAjuda.add(mntmNewMenuItem_1);

        JButton secretaria = new JButton("Secret\u00E1ria");
        secretaria.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        secretaria.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Relatorio_().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        secretaria.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        secretaria.setBounds(404, 529, 554, 141);
        contentPane.add(secretaria);
    }
}
```

### Quarto passo:

Na classe `Gravação_Dados`, olha o seu botão de abrir:

```java
        final JButton Abrir = new JButton("Abrir");
        Abrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Abrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        // Código omitido...

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        Abrir.setBounds(168, 205, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(Abrir);
```

Isso está errado! Você está usando dois actions listeners. Ao clicar pela primeira vez, nada acontece para o usuário, mas ele cria um outro `ActionListener`. Ao clicar na segunda ele salva, mas o primeiro `ActionListener`também roda e cria um terceito `ActionListener`. Ao clicar a terceira vez, ele salva duas vezes e cria um quarto `ActionListener`. Não é isso que você quer. Use apenas um `ActionListener`.

### Quinto passo:

Você já deve estar impaciente, e quanto ao seu propósito de gravar em arquivos `alunoX`, `alunoY`, etc?

Vamos voltar no método `salvar` que criei na classe `Aluno`:

```
    private static final String NOTAS = "C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt";

    private void salvar(String texto) {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NOTAS, true))) {
            writer.write(texto);
            writer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Um erro inesperado ocorreu:\n" + e1.toString());
        }
    }
```

Lembra que adicionei o número do aluno no construtor? Então, logo no começo do construtor, eu o armazeno em um campo, assim, você pode fazer isso:

```
    private static final String NOTAS = "C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\aluno$.txt";

    private void salvar(String texto) {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(NOTAS.replace("$", String.valueOf(numero)), true))) {
            writer.write(texto);
            writer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Um erro inesperado ocorreu:\n" + e1.toString());
        }
    }
```

### Sexto passo:

Na classe `Gravação_Dados`, você lê e salva no mesmo arquivo da classe `Aluno`. Use a mesma técnica de passar o número do aluno como parâmetro no construtor nesta classe. Além disso, separe o código que faz leitura e escrita de arquivos em métodos, nunca os deixe dentro de `ActionListener`s, pois isso é uma má prática de programação.

### Sétimo passo:

As regras de nomenclatura do Java dizem que nomes de variáveis e métodos devem começar com letras minúsculas e seguir o padrão camelCase. Ou seja, utilize `teclado` ao invés de `Teclado`, utilize `abrir` ao invés de `Abrir`, utilize `precisoDeAjuda` ao invés de `Preciso_de_ajuda`, utilize `fazJa` ao invés de `FAZJA`, utilize `adicionarNotas` ao invés `Adicionar_notas`.

As regras de nomenclatura também dizem que classes tem um padrão de nomenclatura semelhante ao de variáveis e métodos, mas começando com letras maiúsculas. Ou seja, use `MenuSobre` ao invés de `Menu_Sobre`.

Essas regras de nomenclatura podem parecer desnecessárias e dispensáveis, mas não são. Ao não segui-las, fica difícil saber se um determinado nome é de uma classe ou de uma variável ou de um método. Aqui mesmo na coloração de sintaxe do StackOverflow ele determina as cores das palavras no código-fonte com base nisso. Esta convenção de nomenclatura não existe a toa.

Além disso, não utilize caracteres acentuados em nomes de classes (ex: `Gravação_Dados`). O motivo disso é que a classe é compilada para um arquivo `<nome da classe>.class`, e uma vez que diferentes sistemas operacionais usam diferentes codificações para caracteres acentuados você acaba introduzindo um problema de portabilidade fazendo com que a sua classe não funcione em outros sistemas operacionais. Algumas ferramentas que leem arquivos `.zip` e `.jar` também têm problemas com acentos em nomes de arquivos.

E por fim o nome das variáveis e classes devem ser bem escolhidos. Por exemplo `PARTE2` é um péssimo nome para uma classe, pois não descreve o que ela faz, o que representa ou qual é a sua finalidade. Já `mntmNewMenuItem_1` também não descreve o que é ou para que serve a variável em questão.

### Outras considerações:

- Para realizar operações de entrada e saída, prefira sempre utilizar o *try-with-resources* para simplificar o código. Um exemplo deste é o método `salvar` que eu demonstrei acima. Mas isso é apenas para Java >= 7.
- Nunca *coma* exceções, ou seja, nunca as negligencie com `} catch (Exception e1) {}`. Simplesmente colocar `} catch (Exception e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }` também não costuma ser bom, uma vez que o seu sistema continua ignorando a ocorrência de um erro como se nada tivesse acontecido. Além disso, em aplicações Swing, muitas vezes o console aonde a exceção vai aparecer não será visível.
- Para facilitar o desenvolvimento, não misture código que manipula arquivos com código que manipula componentes de tela. Ou seja, não os coloque dentro de `ActionListener`s, ao invés disso, os coloque em métodos separados para essa finalidade.
- Evite caminhos de arquivo *hardcoded*. Ou seja, `"C:\\Users\\Jo\u00E3o Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\dica.png"`. Pois isso significa que se você colocar o código em algum computador que não seja o seu, o sistema não vai funcionar! O ideal é usar caminhos relativos para ler e salvar arquivos, ou permitir que o utilizador informe qual é a pasta em que os arquivos estão localizados. No caso das figuras, se a sua aplicação estiver dentro de um arquivo `.jar`, utilizar o método `Class.getResource(String)` seria a melhor opção.
- Convém colocar o `setVisible(true)` dentro do construtor da sua tela, isso evita ter que chamá-lo toda vez que a sua tela é criada.
- Se você estiver usando Java 8, algumas lambda-expressions simplificariam bastante o seu código. Por exemplo, ao invés disso:

```java
    precisoDeAjuda.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Ajuda().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Você pode usar isso:

```java
    precisoDeAjuda.addActionListener(e -> new Ajuda().setVisible(true));
```

Comment: muito obrigado @Victor desde já pelo trabalho todo que teve agora não vou ter muito tempo para fazer o programa mas quando tiver se estiver o que pretendo dou aprovado ou la o que é, muito obrigado

Comment: muito obrigado pelo trabalho que teve !

Comment: @JoaoGil. De nada. Sempre que precisar, haverá alguém aqui no StackOverflow PT disponível para te ajudar.

Comment: não sei como agradecer estou no 12 ano e tenho uma disciplina onde só dou visual basic e pascal e a professora não me sabe ajudar obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @JoaoGil Se esta era a resposta que você estava procurando, clique no botãozinho de "aceitar resposta". Se isso ainda não responde a sua pergunta, explique para poder melhorá-la ainda mais. :)

Comment: tou a ter alguns erros na nova classe com as variaveis aluno e numero mas nao tenho tempo agora mas certamente vou aceitar a sua resposta, nao sei se compilou o code que fez mas deu lhe assim algum erro?

Comment: @JoaoGil Oh, desculpe, estava com dois fecha-parênteses a mais e estava `TextArea` ao invés de `JTextArea`. Na primeira parte, o método `criarCheckDanificado` estava diferente do da segunda parte. Já arrumei. Isso ocorreu porque mexi bastante nos arquivos e a versão que eu havia copiado-e-colado aqui não era a última, mas agora está certo.

Comment: amigo Victor estive um tempo fora sem programar mas agora estive a dar uma grande vista de olhos ao programa, em vez de aparecer uma mensagem para eu dizer o numero e o nome eu queria que logo que o utilizador aperta-se o botão ele soubesse em que file ia escrever, o mal foi meu porque devia ter especificado que queria vários documentos txt em vez de um só chamado notas se se lembra